# Constructor runs once in multi-Instantiates of a class in "builder pattern" in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, builder-pattern

I have a class in my react app which uses 'Builder Pattern' and I've imported it in some nested components in my page. for example in parent component and child component, too.

But it seems it calls the class's constructor once! and in second instantiate it has existing data which I've added in previews in previews instantiate. (Not a new and clean instantiate!)

```
// [Builder pattern] 
class Requester {
    constructor() {
        this.definedHeaders = {}
        console.log('construct', this)

    }

    contentType(contenttype) {
        this.definedHeaders['Content-Type'] = contenttype
        return this;
    }

    async get(url) {
        // ...
    }

    async post(url, data = {}, isFormData = false) {
         // ...
    }
}

export default new Requester();
```

Comment: semi colons are missing in your code

Comment: @PunithaSubramaniYoganyaaS Are you JS developer!?

Comment: Yes @Pouya Jabbarisani

Comment: Why do you expect it to run multiple times? It's called once, when `export default new Requester()` singleton instance is exported. *and in second instantiate it* - what does this mean? IThe question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus as I said, I'm importing it in different components.

Comment: As @estus pointed out when writing `export default new Requester()`, you are exporting singelton instance. Just use `export default Requester` and use `let requester = new Requester()` while consuming.

Comment: @tarzenchugh But when I'm importing it in different files, it must give a new instance, right?

Comment: When importing in different files using `export default new Class()` it will be singleton (same instance) but with `export default Class` new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES modules are evaluated only once, when they are imported the first time. This trait is common to all JavaScript module implementations.

Because of that, exporting class instance is a common way to make class a singleton. That a class itself isn't exported prevents from creating additional instances.

If the intention is to not have a single instance, a class itself should be exported:

```
export default class Requester {...}
```

And instantiated in places where it's used:

```
import Requester from '...';

const requester = new Requester;
```